# OpenCV Cascade Classifier iOS 7

Tags: ios, opencv

I tried writing a face detection app to familiarize myself with OpenCV for iOS but the Cascade Classifier does not work. Here is the code:

```
    - (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image
    {
        cv::Mat grayImage;
        std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

        cv::cvtColor(image, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::equalizeHist(grayImage, grayImage);
        self.faceDetector.detectMultiScale(grayImage, faces);

        for (std::vector<cv::Rect>::iterator it = faces.begin(); it != faces.end();
              it++)
            cv::rectangle(image, *it, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    }
```

I have checked the the cascade classifier was loaded and image is non-null. The debugger reveals that `faces` is empty even after calling detectMultiScale. I am using `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` to load my classifier. Image [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~chuck/lennapg/lena_std.tif).

EDIT

Based on lightalchemist and berak's suggestions I tried using `haarcascade_frontalface_alt` and `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2` and switching images but it does not work. `faces.isEmpty()` returns true even after `detectMultiscale` is called.

When I tried compiling it for Mac it worked perfectly. Could this be an iOS 7/OpenCV bug?

Comment: Try a couple of images with faces in them and see if the detector detects faces in *any* of them. The face detector is not guaranteed to work perfectly. There are times it will fail to detect faces. Another thing is try to use the one xml file with for frontal faces with "alt2" as part of the name. I vaguely remember that that set of parameters works better.

Comment: usually, haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml works better.